# How to record system audio? (Soundflower not working)

Tags: audio, quicktime, screen-capture, soundflower

I've been trying to record some system audio from my computer while screen capturing in Quicktime Player. The thing is, I've done this before. I've recorded myself talking and the system audio through an aggregate device in Soundflower. I was also able to hear the system audio by using a multi-output device as my output.

For clarification, here are screenshots of the setups I've tried.

This is the first one I tried, because it's what I remembered from what I did before.

[image]

[image]

With this setup, I was able to hear the sound from my computer, but could not adjust the volume, and when I tried, instead of the usual popup showing the changing volume, I got this:

[image]

When I tried recording audio using Quicktime Player, it picked up the sound from my microphone, but no system audio.

When this setup didn't work, I searched for an answer on google. Every single tutorial I saw said to set Soundflower (2ch) as both my input and output. (Some said only to set it as output, but then later chose it as the input for Quicktime Player). I tried that like so:

[image]

With this setup, I could not hear any sound from my computer. However, I could adjust the volume on my computer, not that it seemed to do anything. I tried recording with Quicktime Player, but it didn't record either the volume from my microphone or the system audio.

I would like to have a setup that only records my system audio, and one that records both my mic and system audio. Optimally, I'd be able to hear the system audio in both cases.

I checked to make sure that the audio wasn't just really quiet, and I did all the basic things like restarting my computer.

So, what should I do? I'd be happy to provide any more details if necessary.

EDIT: An update. I noticed that with the second setup, I was able to hear Skype calls (people talking, not just the ringing), despite not being able to hear anything else. Also, people on Skype were able to hear me with the first setup, but not the second. In neither case could they hear the system audio. Not sure if this is useful information or not, I just wanted to be as detailed as possible.

Comment: I would to find out more on this too, not luck so far

Comment: maybe raise a bounty?

Comment: Try audio hijack from the same company (IIRC) that created soundflower.

Answer (score 1):

That may be offtopic, but as you did not write your OS version, can it be you have a macOS version where Soundflower is incompatible with? Running updates lately?

I had to switch to Blackhole: [Blackhole - a replacement for Soundflower](https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole)

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to have a setup that only records my system audio, and one that records both my mic and system audio. Optimally, I'd be able to hear the system audio in both cases.

I often had this issue trying to record conference calls.

Now that most conference call apps (at least Slack, Skype, Zoom, Google Hangouts) support setting a mic and speaker, it's possible to adjust the output volume that *you* can hear independently of what QuickTime hears.

When QuickTime wasn't catching any system audio, I had usually forgotten to do this:

- Select **Soundflower (2ch)** as system output (in System Preferences or from the speaker icon in the menu bar)
- Turn the output volume up

  - This is what QuickTime "hears"
- Set system output back to whatever speakers/headphones/etc. you are listening to and adjust the output volume for comfort

### Setup

- Exactly as you posted above from **Audio MIDI Setup**, I just named the devices differently:
- Aggregate Device **Mic+SF** with these devices selected:

  - Built-in Microphone (or other microphone)
  - **Soundflower (2ch)**
- Multi-output Device **Internal Recording** with these devices selected:

  - Built-in Output (or other speakers/headphones)
  - **Soundflower (2ch)**

### Record system audio *without* mic

- Ensure app you want to record is using **Internal Recording** as output
- Ensure QuickTime is using **Soundflower (2ch)** as input

  - In the New Screen Recording window, click the **V** next to the recording button to select the input source

### Record system audio *with* mic

- Ensure app you want to record is using **Internal Recording** as output
- Ensure QuickTime is using **Mic+SF** as input